# Include reviews made outside of /review in progress towards the badge

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, review

The recent changes to `/review` has gotten everyone interested in cleaning up the muck. At present, only posts "reviewed" (by clicking on the review link) and actions taken (up/down/close/edit/flag) from within `/review` count towards the badge.

However, it is entirely possible that one catches a poor question outside of `/review` (e.g., on the front page/tag page, etc.) and "reviews" it and takes some action on it. However, these actions do not count for the badge, at present. In all likelihood, this question would've also been in the `/review` queue and if one were fortuitous enough to have reviewed it there, these actions would've counted towards the badge.

**Would it be possible to include reviews made outside of `/review` to count *if* the question was also in the review queue?** Note that this shouldn't apply if the question dropped out of the queue (either by inaction or after it was edited and improved by previous reviews).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does count towards the badge. Sort of. If you review/dismiss a post from the review section that you've previously acted on in some way, those actions seem to be tracked retroactively.

Comment: NB: If you review a post from the `/review` page, open it in a separate tab/window, and take action on it there, your action(s) _do_ count towards your review stats. However, review actions you take on _other_ posts in the same new tab/window do not count.

Comment: What badge are you talking about?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478/reviewer @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ

Comment: Hmmm... What qualifies as a "review"? Clicking on the "review" link?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionஇ_இ - yes just clicking the link seems to increment the "review" count.

Comment: Related:  ["Why directly voting to close a question does not add to your number of reviews in the queue?"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11072) on SE.Physics.Meta.

Answer (score 20):

I actually thought about suggesting this myself -- I *constantly* come across posts in /review that I've already acted on* -- but I have come to the conclusion that it is not a good idea.

The point of the badge (I think) is to get you (me, us) onto the /review page and cranking through a dozen or more reviews at a time.

That goal is not served by counting review-like actions that are performed in the course of normal site use.

As much as I'd like a new badge real fast, too, I have to disagree with this proposal.

---

*I tried removing, then reinstating a vote on one post to see if it would count for my review stats, but it didn't seem to.

Comment: 1000 reviews is 1000 reviews. It shouldn't matter how they are done.

Comment: @Pubby8: I guess I'd say they're not _reviews_ if they're not performed on the review page. The badge isn't called Site Maintenance.

Comment: It's too bad that my actions on the review page prior to the new implementation don't count toward the badge. I used to spend a lot of time in the `/review` page before this happened, it was a great source of flaggable posts. I don't visit it as much anymore at the moment.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, indeed, but of course that's impossible. In a similar vein, I had worked my way up to 750 flag weight very shortly after its introduction, but _before_ the creation of either Deputy or Marshal badges. We just have to keep things in perspective...

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Yeah I know, of course. It's just one of those "doh" moments.

Comment: I think you are missing what yoda is getting at, there are some of us who already had our own review methodology in place. It is *really* *really* redundant to review a post when your name shows you edited the post 5 mins before outside of /review.

Comment: @phwd: When I go through /review, looking at my "home" tags, I find that I've already acted on 90% of the posts.

Answer (score 3):

**No, I don't think this would be a good idea**

Initially I was thinking the same thing (more or less as I was writing [Opening a question / answer from the review page doesn't mark it as having been “reviewed”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113059/opening-a-question-answer-from-the-review-page-doesnt-mark-it-as-having-been)), but then I realised that the point of the review statistics / badge is to ***encourage people to use the /review page***.

The review page is a fantastic tool (especially as posts now disappear from the list as they are reviewed), however even as someone who quite likes going around cleaning up questions / answers I still found I never really used it until it was "gamified" - instead I used to just randomly browse the site.  The problem with this is that I focus on the questions that look interesting, *not those that need attention*.

The /review page is all about highlighting questions that need attention and the "gamification" is all about getting people to use this page.

Answer (score 3):

Given we're fulfilling the purpose of the review queue by interacting with the post on the Q&A, I think that our interactions with posts in the review queue while not on the review page should count towards the review badges.

This would help improve the quality of the site in general because users will be further encouraged to upvote, comment, and help while on the Q&A portion more than they currently do. Users are further encouraged to interact with more posts in general regardless of whether or not they know that they are in the review queue.

I realize that the review queue is there for us to go through multiple at a time (and it still will be), but I do not see why the badge should be restricted to reviewing posts on the review page and not in general.

Answer (score 2):

> However, it is entirely possible that one catches a poor question outside of /review

*Stop right there*, I'm missing **answers** in this sentence. Most `/review`-ing users would not check the entire page on whether first answers conform to the FAQ and whether all the answers are all of sufficient quality. If you are on the site your main intention is to browse around and do stuff where you see fit, but that doesn't guarantee that you see everything; the `/review` tab on the other hand has been designed that all the stuff that needs reviewing is put together.

So, if your intention is to review it's really more handy to use the `/review` tab. But then you came up with the problem that can be annoying to an extent if you are really dedicated to browsing the site:

> One catches a poor question outside of /review and "reviews" and takes some action on it.

The solution would be to implement a logic like:

```
IF lastEditor IS you AND lastEditDate BIGGER THAN putOnReviewPageDate THEN hide
```

This guarantees that when you did act, it is hidden. It takes no assumption on whether you've seen it...