# Strunk & White and Review Stats

Tags: support, review, edit-badges

Having gotten the Strunk & White badge, I can now see my review stats.  The trouble is, I see nothing but zeroes both for today, and all.

[image]

In the past I've clicked through plenty of questions both in the "First Questions" and "First Answers" tabs on StackOverflow.com/review and voted/edited many of them.

Do the review stats not start *accruing* until you get Strunk & White?  I was under the impression that getting this badge simply allowed you to *view* these stats.

Comment: Do you click "review question/answer" or just the title link?

Comment: @random - Ohhhhhh.  Can you make this an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I've clicked on "Review Question" multiple times before getting the Strunk and White badge today.  I also got all zeroes the first time I viewed the stats.

Comment: @Zoot - after clicking on the review question link on a few questions, do you still get all zeroes?

Comment: I started at zero after Strunk and White.  I'm now at 2.  The question that still hasn't been answered is "Do the review stats not start accruing until you get Strunk & White? I was under the impression that getting this badge simply allowed you to view these stats."  I've now spent 150 of my 200 rep to get an answer, since I spent quite a bit of time flagging, editing, and reviewing before getting the badge, and seeing all zeros makes it seems like none of the work mattered at all.  It was incredibly frustrating, and I basically stopped reviewing because of it.

Comment: Review stats do not in any way depend on the S&W badge.  S&W badge only allows you to see the stats.  Having said that, to get credit for "reviewing" a post, you have to click the review link from the review page.  If you don't click the review link, it won't count as a review.

Comment: @Zoot: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116386/do-actions-before-i-unlock-reviewer-count - waffles confirms my answer there in a comment.

Comment: @Zoot - also, please don't review just to get a badge.  Review because you care about Stack Overflow and want to help clean up a bit.  I try to plow through the 10K quasi-moderator queue at least once a day because I love SO so much.  I'm not working toward any badge (that I'm aware of)

Comment: @Mat - you may want to add that as an answer.  It looks like random's answer is correct but incomplete.

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm not reviewing just to get a badge.  I was just curious to find out how much work I had done, since the text in the sidebar seemed to express that I would be able to look at how much work I'd done once I had received a badge.  Most of the work I'd been doing was flagging, and I was looking forward to seeing how much flagging I had done, and the amount of reviews versus amount of flags.  I like looking at metrics.  Seeing all zeros doesn't tell me anything.  If I had clearly been warned about this, it wouldn't have been an issue.

Comment: @Zoot - ok, fair enough.  I didn't know the metrics didn't start until you hit S&W.  I thought mine were all 0 since I hadn't been using the review links.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order for your reviews to "count" by the tracker, you'll need to click on the "review question" or "review answer" link that appears per post.

If you click on the title and go out of the /review field of vision, [your reviews and actions on the posts will not be counted/tallied](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111482/include-reviews-made-outside-of-review-in-progress-towards-the-badge).

Comment: This is a bit confusing, to put it mildly. Clicking the title is the obvious way to review :-)

Comment: I click on the "review question/answer" link and stay within that view, but no edits, votes, or comments seem to get tallied.

Comment: Odd that a bounty was opened on this, but it looks like another 100 meta rep may be coming your way—PROFIT

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what random said...

> Do the review stats not start accruing until you get Strunk & White?

This is correct.  No matter how much you review, your stats will remain at all zeros until you have S&W.

Comment: This should be indicated in the "edit posts to see your review stats!" sidebar in the review section.

Comment: @Zoot IMO it is, just not explicitly.  "Track your review progress" means to me that it is currently *not* be tracked.

Comment: I have entered a feature request to make this verbiage clearer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117916/153579