# Do review actions taken before unlocking Strunk & White count?

Tags: support, badges, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Strunk & White and Review Stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111699/strunk-white-and-review-stats)

I am a big fan of the "review" page. I review a lot of things, and am working towards the Strunk and White badge.

It says on the review page that getting Strunk and White unlocks Reviewer. Does that mean that anything I do related to reviewing before I unlock Strunk & White doesn't count toward the Reviewer badge?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is correct. All the review stats start at zero once you unlock Strunk & White.

Comment: confirmed .... this is the case