# How to calculate the Reviewer badge using SQL Query

Tags: discussion, badges, review-stats, review-badges

Is there any way to calculate how far somebody is from Reviewer badge using an SQL Query?

Comment: Adding "Thanks" to the end of your post [is considered unnecessary here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Addressing the post to "Sir" is incorrect and possibly rude since there will be many readers, some of whom are not male, and it is likewise unnecessary. Please do not rollback your post to re-instate those elements and remove the grammatical corrections that were made to it.

Comment: You may also be interested in the ["People can edit my posts?!" section](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#editing) of the FAQ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have [Stunk & White badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) to see review stats as shown by bluefeet.

See [Strunk & White and Review Stats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111699/178505)

> Is there any way to calculate how far somebody is from Reviewer badge
>   using any SQL Query?

And I don't think there is anyway to get review stats from data explorer.

Answer (score 7):

When you go the the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) screen, the right side should display the stats:

[image]

You will see your stats once you have the [Strunk & White Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white). Prior to getting the Strunk & White badge you should see how many posts you have edited on the right side of the review screen.