# What should I do when a user repeatedly rejects or roll-backs valid edits to his/her post(s)?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rollbacks, rejected-edits

I know the rules of [editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) [your own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84517/can-you-approve-edits-to-your-own-posts) but what should be done when a user consistently rejects and/or rolls-back a valid edit to their original version.

I am curious after my experience with [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136935/how-to-calculate-the-reviewer-badge-using-sql-query).  Yes, I can understand maybe I didn't offer up the best [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/3636) but the user then received another perfectly valid edit and roll-back to the initial version.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening especially when the edits were valid?  If there is no way to prevent it, should something be said in the comments or how should this  situation be handled?

Flagging a mod seems *excessive* especially when they are busy with other items.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Edit again **after** leaving a comment pointing to the Meta post explaining the community consensus on the topic. Something like:

> Welcome to `[insert site name]`! To keep a high signal-to-noise ratio, questions and answers should not contain salutations, signatures or "thanks". See also: [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

If that doesn't work, flag requesting a post lock.

Comment: +1; just leave a comment with the relevant citation(s).

Comment: thanks for confirming leaving and comment and then flagging for mod attention.

Answer (score 6):

I think flagging a moderator is *exactly* what you should do when you need help in handling an edit war. It's the *main purpose* for moderators in a community.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/olBxw.png]