# Can "Actioned" be extended to cover the question and other answers for a reviewed answer?

Tags: feature-request, review

My usual workflow on `/review` is to look at answers - first, late, and low quality - far more than questions. (There are more of them and less auto-checks on them.) Often in addition to voting/editing/flagging/commenting the answer, I will do some of those for the question or for another answer.

For example, bad answers are quite often inspired by bad questions, or are "thanks man that's great" non-answers to a question that has a good answer, and so on.

However, none of those actions accumulate my reviewing stats unless they happen to be taken on the answer that led me there. Is it possible to expand this scope of influence at all? (I mean technically, can the team do it with less effort than just randomly updating those tickers whenever I edit/flag/vote/comment in the normal course of my life.)

Comment: I've been thinking of suggesting myself for the past day or two. I've been hitting `/review` pretty hard, and I definitely take action on a lot of posts that I only see _because of_ a post actually listed on `/review`. In my mind, that's still in the spirit of the badge.

Comment: Related but fundamentally different feature request: [Include review made outside of review in progress towards the badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111482/include-reviews-made-outside-of-review-in-progress-towards-the-badge)