# Shouldn't posts that I reviewed from the main site be hidden from "/review"?

Tags: feature-request, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include reviews made outside of /review in progress towards the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111482/include-reviews-made-outside-of-review-in-progress-towards-the-badge)

I'm quite active on the main site, and mostly catch *first questions* and *first answers* when they appear. I'll probably edit them, or flag as "not an answer", et cetera.

Later, when I go to `/review`, I see all of those posts again. I don't want to click through all of these again. In fact, the statistics change in a very weird way when you do so (see example below).

Therefore: Shouldn't they already be hidden, because I've reviewed them?

I understand that it's helpful to be able to go through them once again, but there could be a button `Hide all reviewed` or similar. In fact, it already says: "Hiding reviewed and closed posts", but it's not really doing that – because I've reviewed the posts, just not through `/review`.

---

### Example

I've seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/356944/how-can-i-make-my-ip-address-appear-to-be-from-another-country-to-watch-iplayer) right when it came up, and I know I edited it and voted to close as a duplicate. `/review` however still shows me this post.

[image]

Before I click "review question" here, my stats say:

[image]

When I click it, I see that I've already been there:

[image]

Suddenly, my stats change:

[image]

Comment: @random this was not an exact duplicate, the problem is that review is not properly hiding posts viewed using the review post feature, it's not related to the linked post at all.

Comment: Posts not hiding when touched in `/review` is another question entirely. This one was about making action outside of that view count toward that view @ben

Comment: @random Well, to be honest, I said: *> Shouldn't they already be hidden, because I've reviewed them?*, and *> In fact, it already says: "Hiding reviewed and closed posts", but it's not really doing that*. All I want is to hide those. In that way it's different from the other question.

Comment: It will only count as reviewed if you look at it from /review. That's what the "Hiding reviewed" part is about. That's what the other request is wanting, to track your review habits outside of the `/review` portal. If this was about the posts not being hidden while you're attacking them via /review, then no, it would not be that duplicate

Comment: @random See what you mean now. Guess you're right, there's a certain dependency.

Comment: @random my head's all mixed up then. I'm thinking more of what this question is bringing up: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111393/posts-ive-already-reviewed-show-up-in-the-review-section-again But there's no attention surrounding this. It appears posts that only I have reviewed still show up, or so I assume; I'm noticing it a lot on UX.SE, which does not have many reviewers. A bunch of posts I know where reviewed and previously hidden (the close tab, which doesn't have many posts) have come back. This seems to be recent actually.