# Opening a question / answer from the review page doesn't mark it as having been "reviewed"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, review, review-stats

I've been having a play around with the [latest review changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/review-early-review-often/), in particular with the extra "Your Review Stats" panel that has been added to the review page.  Initially however it took me a while to figure out what it is I needed to do to get questions to count as having been "reviewed" - usually when using this page I middle click (open in a new window) the title of the post:

[image: Screenshot of where I click on the review page]

I then go through the open tabs reviewing  and **editing** as appropriate, however this appears to do absolutely nothing to any of the stats on the "Your Review Stats" pane even after having refreshed the review page:

[image: Screenshot of the review pane after "reviewing" some posts]

It seems that in order to get the numbers in the "Your Review Stats" pane to update I need to click on the "review answer" button instead - in fact clicking on this button for a question I had already edited automatically increased my "Edited" stat without me needing to do anything else to that question.

So my question is: *Should clicking on the post title make a post contribute toward my review statistics or is this intended behaviour?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is: Should clicking on the post title make a post contribute toward my review statistics or is this intended behaviour?

My intention was to keep people on the `/review` path during the review process. A few people prefer to click on the title links and I agree it should count as being reviewed **if and only if** you are hitting it from the review path. Will see if I can hook that up.

Comment: +1, my previous workflow was to open each in a different tab and work through the whole page. Often 1 bad answer led to 2-3 other bad answers, or even was rooted in a bad question. The `/review` page is too busy as-is.

Comment: @sixlettervariables completed .. to be deployed today

Comment: This setting is problematic for me, and potentially for others: I don't have the expertise to review _any_ question. Thus, I used to click on the question first to check it out, and if I decided I could review it, I went ahead and did so. But often enough I decided to let somebody else do the reviewing for a specific question. The way it is now, I can't just check out questions without officially reviewing them. Perhaps a question should be counted as reviewed either if action is taken or if a "reviewed" link is clicked? Should I make a feature-request or am I the only one having trouble here?

Answer (score 1):

> Should clicking on the post title make a post contribute toward my review statistics or is this intended behavior?

I would say it is the intended behavior, as what you should do is to click on the "review answer" (or "review question") link you find after the post.

[image: screenshot]

Once you do that, the post will be entirely shown, and you will notice the elements to vote, vote to close a question (this links is shown only when you are reviewing a question), edit the post, flag it, or comment it.

[image: screenshot]

In the case of answers, the question is shown too, to allow you to understand if the answer is really an answer.

Every time you click on "review answer" (or "review question"), the review counter is increased, even if you don't take any action. For example, you could review the post, and see that there is nothing to do. Of course, in that case the post in not counted as actioned post.

Some users reported that, clicking the "review answer" link, opening the posts in a different tab, and taking an action on that tab (e.g. editing the post, or voting it) is counted as actioned post. I didn't verify this, but if this is the case, then it is what you could do. In any case, you should click on the "review answer" link.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The OP asks for how the site *should* work not how it does work.

Comment: Yep - I figured that out, I just wasnt sure if it was intended behaviour.  I don't like attempting to review posts "in-line" in the review page as you can't see the context of the rest of the question.  Now I normally open the question as I did before so it means I need to do the extra "review answer" click just to get the review to count.  It strikes me that opening the post from this page should do the same thing.

Comment: @N.N. The question I read is, "Should clicking on the post title make a post contribute toward my review statistics or is this intended behaviour?" I am replying that is the intended behavior. In which way this answer doesn't answer the asked question?

Comment: @kiamlaluno I understood the question as normative and not only as descriptive. The OP's comment above implies that the raised question also is about whether current behavior should be as is or be changed.