# New First Posts Review Queue: Track valid actions across tabs

Tags: feature-request, review

As I use the New First Posts Review Queue, I find myself opening the original post in another tab to better see the context.

After doing this, I make an edit, add a comment, upvote or whatever. This is not registered as a valid action in the review tab. :(

Is there a way to track these valid actions across open tabs, or is the solution just to buck up and remember to switch back to my review tab before making my changes?

Comment: This was also [suggested for the previous review system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111482/include-reviews-made-outside-of-review-in-progress-towards-the-badge) but nothing came of it.

Comment: @animuson This is different because the review dialogue is being actively used, and it is a question that is being reviewed using the dialogue that is open in the other tab. Perhaps there could be an ajax listener in the review tab that notes changes made by the reviewer from the other tab?